# Odoo res.groups Boolean instead of Dropdown

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10, access-rights

i have developed a custom module and in that custom module i am trying to give my own access rights.

for that purpose i have created a xml with access groups and a csv that specifies appropriate access right now all this is working quite fine

But i want the selection of access right to not be a dropdown but a boolean select field that lets me choose which level i would like to assign

```
<record id="group_user" model="res.groups">
 <field name="name">Executive</field>
 <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
 <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
 <field name="category_id" ref="my_module.module_management"/>
</record>
```

now i get a dropdown on the user page in application however i would like for this to show below it in a boolean group

Answer (score 0):

I show one example to how the **boolean field** is work in **group**

create a gruoup category A

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_a">
    <field name="name">A</field>
    <field name="sequence">10</field>
</record>
```

Add manager group to the category A. Automatically checks the manager group

```
<record id="group_a_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_name.module_category_a"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

Add user group to category A.

```
<record id="group_a_user" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">User</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_name.module_category_a"/>
</record>
```

This will shows the groups manager and user under A.
There is a boolean field option for both user and manager.

Comment: Yes this is a excellent dmonstration of adding boolena in groups with the only disadvantage of not being able to provide "Implies id" . Do you have any suggestions for that ?

Comment: @ Daim Sayed: no,I don't no how to handle implied_ids with this.